# how to convert a string with equal "=" sign to json in c#

Tags: c#, json, string

I have following string, this returns from the web service

```
"Status=Success,PNR=76UUEI78787870,Customer_Ref=89511133545"
```

I want to convert this in to json like below

```
{
    "Status": "Success",
    "PNR": "76UUEI78787870",
    "Customer_Ref": "89511133545"
}
```

how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "Status=Success,PNR=76UUEI78787870,Customer_Ref=89511133545";
var vals = str.Split(',');
var json = "{" +
            string.Join(",",
                vals.Select(val => val.Split('=')).Select(s => string.Format("\"{0}\": \"{1}\"", s[0], s[1]))) +
            "}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code that uses `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
var paramList = "Status=Success,PNR=76UUEI78787870,Customer_Ref=89511133545";
var dict = paramList.Split(',').Select(x => x.Split('=')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1])
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
```

It handles things like quotes inside names properly.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
private static string format_json(string json)
{
    json = json.Replace('=',":");
    dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

This would work with `newtonsoft.Json` and `json.net` library

Answer (score 0):

You could convert a given string to `Dictionary` and serialize using `Json.Net` as below.

```
string s =  @"Status=Success,PNR=76UUEI78787870,Customer_Ref=89511133545";

var dictionary = s.Split(',')   // create a dictionary.
 .Select(x=>x.Split('='))
 .ToDictionary(x=>x[0], x=>x[1]);   

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( dictionary, new KeyValuePairConverter( ) );

//output 
// {"Status":"Success","PNR":"76UUEI78787870","Customer_Ref":"89511133545"}
```

Check this [`fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OEwTu0)

Answer (score 0):

Consider working with StringBuilder (specially if performance is important and if you need to work with bigger strings in the future).

```
        string sourceString = "Status=Success,PNR=76UUEI78787870,Customer_Ref=89511133545";
        StringBuilder bufferString = new StringBuilder();
        bufferString.Append("{\"").Append(sourceString)
            .Replace(",", "\",\"")
            .Replace("=", "\": \"")
            .Append("\"}");
        string outputString = bufferString.ToString();
        /*
         * libraries like Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package could help prettify the output string if needed
        */
        string prettyJSON = JValue.Parse(bufferString.ToString()).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

Note: This consistently outperform  the use of the string methods.